# java always show system tray message

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application, tray

how to display a message to the system tray so that it did not disappear after a certain time (usually hidden by 10 sec)
Posts deduce the standard method

```
trayIcon.displayMessage("Action Event",
                            message,
                            TrayIcon.MessageType.WARNING);


                }
```

where

```
public enum MessageType {
    /** An error message */
    ERROR,
    /** A warning message */
    WARNING,
    /** An information message */
    INFO,
    /** Simple message */
    NONE
};
```

tried with different but all the same.

Most likely it should be done as it is not through a different message.
Requires that the message is always shown as you do not click on it

Comment: how you try to do that?

Comment: `ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setDismissDelay(12000);` will help you... You might as well use the `UIDefaults` from the `UIManager`.